# jQuery media queries

Tags: jquery, plugins, media-queries

I am using a plugin called beforeAfter (http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/) and the way have implemented it i would like to ONLY corporate the click even in when the user is using a screen say 580px. Now i have the development code for it but unsure how to add in the media query for this.

Here is a link for the full code
http://jsbin.com/ojuwid/1/

And here is the snippet in the plugin file i need to incorporate into a media query:

```
// When clicking in the container, move the bar and imageholder divs
                $(obj).click(function(e){
                    var clickX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                    $('#dragwrapper'+randID).stop().animate({'left':clickX-($('#dragwrapper'+randID).width()/2)+'px'},o.clickSpeed);
                    $('div:eq(2)', obj).stop().animate({'width':clickX+'px'},o.clickSpeed);
                    $('#lt-arrow'+randID+',#rt-arrow'+randID).stop().animate({opacity:0},50);
                });
                $(obj).one('mousemove', function(){$('#dragwrapper'+randID).stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);}); 

// If the mouse is over the container and we animate the intro, we run this to change the opacity when the mouse moves since the hover event doesnt get triggered yet
                }
            });
```

If anyone has any thoughts or methods of how they would do this that would be great! PS-I know media queries are a CSS Concept- just unsure how to trigger off the window resize query into this plugin.

Comment: Can you just add a condition like `if($(window).width() <= 580)` ?

Comment: Would this just go into the plugin script itself? Sorry about this!

Comment: See andwer for the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just add a condition like `if($(window).width() <= 580)` ?

The code will look like this :

```
    // When clicking in the container, move the bar and imageholder divs
                    $(obj).click(function(e){
                        if($(window).width() <= 580) { //added this line
                            var clickX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                            $('#dragwrapper'+randID).stop().animate({'left':clickX-($('#dragwrapper'+randID).width()/2)+'px'},o.clickSpeed);
                            $('div:eq(2)', obj).stop().animate({'width':clickX+'px'},o.clickSpeed);
                            $('#lt-arrow'+randID+',#rt-arrow'+randID).stop().animate({opacity:0},50);
                        } //added this line too
                    });
                    $(obj).one('mousemove', function(){$('#dragwrapper'+randID).stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);}); 

    // If the mouse is over the container and we animate the intro, we run this to change the opacity when the mouse moves since the hover event doesnt get triggered yet
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for this - Was not sure i had to take the function out of the plugin or if i could use the if function within it. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a mediaQuery? How about just checking the size of the window via js before binding the event?

```
if(window.screen.width <= 580) {
    //...bind the event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be inconsistencies between your media queries and jQuery's $(window).width(), so you might want to try checking [changed CSS properties](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries) instead that correspond with the media queries you have. This should ensure consistency between when your CSS media queries are applied and when jQuery handles the click.